# How do I log the request and response in soapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui, loadui

I am calling a REST based service from SoapUI. I have created a load test for the service and the test works. I wrote the following code in my setup script for the load test.

```
log.info("This is from the setup script")
def request = context.expand('${#Request}')
log.info(request)
def response = context.expand('${#Response}')
log.info(response);
```

The only item I am getting in my log is the "This is from the setup script". 
I also added the following lines of code in my Teardown script.

```
log.info("Teardown script")
def response = context.expand('${#Response}')
log.info(response);
```

I am not seeing the "Teardown script" text in the log. At this point I am a bit puzzled as to the behavior.

**Load Test:**
[image: This is my load test]

**Test Suite**

[image: This is my test suite]

**Test case options.** 
I have unchecked the Discard OK results test box.
[image: Test case options]

What changes do I need to do to my scripts in order to log the requests and the responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a setup and/or teardown script, remember those are run only **once** per run, not per test! What you intended is not going to work.

In your setup, since no tests have run yet, the `context` is going to be empty ... as you can see from your log message.

In your teardown, I suspect there is a bug in SoapUI and the log is not getting sent to the log tab. If you intentionally create an error (I used `logg.info "Hello world!"` - note the intentional double g), I still got a an error in the error log tab.

Comment: So how do I make it log the request / response for each test?

Comment: You have to do it as a test step. However, it is important to note that logging will completely defeat the purpose of a load test, as the act of logging will heavily distort the performance. Or, just run your test as a simple SoapUI test, in a loop from command line, with the `-A` option.

Comment: I am not familiar with the command line yet, but I have run it in a loop from the UI.

Comment: You want this http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html then.